# JQuery not working on Wordpress Admin page

Tags: php, jquery, wp-admin, javascript

I am currently using the GeoDirectory add-on for Wordpress and as of late, I haven't made any changes to Wordpress other than the fact that wordpress has upgraded to the latest version.

When I add an event, without a package then JQuery appears to be working fine, everything on the page appears and works the way it should so the link it like...

wp-admin/post.php?post=0000&action=edit

With that link JQuery is working, however when I select a package which you have to do the URL changes which throws up errors within the console when I view it...
The URL when the package is selected changes to this...

wp-admin/post.php?post=0000&action=edit&package_id=2

These are the errors that get thrown up..

[image]

It almost appears as though with the extra tag on the end of the URL the JQuery is not being read at all?

Answer (score 2):

There are this type of problem occure. In case-

**1-** jQuery function conflict to other jquery function.
    To remove this type of problem, define below script in **wp-config.php** file.

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

**2-** jQuery liberaray file are not include in frontend.

**3-** Jquery same file defined more than one time. then this type of issue show in firebug.

Comment: You just saved my day. Thank you for this treasure config.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting your scripts indicate that the script should work when connected to jQuery:

```
  function my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script', plugins_url('/js/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script');
```

stated that the need: array('jquery')